# Difference between magnitude_spectrum result available in matplotlib.mlab and numpy.abs(numpy.fft.fft(data))

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, signal-processing, fft

I have a simple sine wave. I am trying to find the magnitude spectrum in frequency domain.
I used the function `matplotlib.mlab.magnitude_spectrum(data)`
I wanted to verify this result, so I tried `numpy.abs(numpy.fft.fft(data))`
The results are different.
It should be same right? Even if I try
 `numpy.sqrt(matplotlib.mlab.psd(data))`, the results are different.

I am looking for the explanation for this.

Answer (score 4):

There are two main differences. Firstly, [`matplotlib.mlab.magnitude_spectrum`](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.magnitude_spectrum) applies a window function to the input data before taking the FFT (by default, a [Hanning window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Hann_.28Hanning.29_window)). Secondly, it returns only the positive frequencies, whereas `np.fft.fft` returns both positive and negative frequencies:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


x = np.random.randn(500)

mag1, f = plt.mlab.magnitude_spectrum(x)

# apply a hanning window to x
xw = np.hanning(x.shape[0]) * x

# use np.fft.rfft to get the positive frequencies only
mag2 = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(xw))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.hold(True)
ax.plot(f, mag1, '-k', lw=2)
ax.plot(f, mag2, '--r', lw=2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

[`matplotlib.mlab.psd`](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.psd) does something more sophisticated - it computes the periodogram using [Welch's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_method), rather than just taking the squared magnitude of the FFT. It basically takes the average periodogram over windowed overlapping segments of your signal, giving you a 'smoother' periodogram that is more robust to noise, at the expense of some frequency resolution. Depending on what your signal looks like, and your choice of `NFFT=` and `noverlap=` parameters to `psd`, you should expect the result to look quite different to that of `magnitude_spectrum`.

Comment: Thank you. By default noverlap = 0 and NFFT = 256. But if if I change NFFT to the length of the signal and if i calculate the square of the power restruned by psd function, I should get same result as magnitude_spectrum right?

Comment: No, there are several other differences. `psd` computes `result.conj() * result`, whereas `magnitude_spectrum` computes `np.abs(result)` (where `result` contains the FFT coefficients). By default, `psd` also divides by the sampling rate to give density in units of Hz^-1 (you can disable this with `scale_by_freq=False`). It also scales the spectrum by the norm of the window to compensate for windowing loss. If you really want to know exactly how it works, you should probably take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/mlab.py#L654-L806).

Comment: Ok. My task is to find the difference between the magnitude of input and received signal in frequency domain. The difference obtained by psd and magnitude_spectrum is very different. Which one should I use to calculate the magnitude and phase difference in frequency domain?

Comment: And the resolution provided by magnitude_spectrum and numpy.fft.fft(data) is too much for my task.

Comment: Those are separate questions that would be much more appropriate for [dsp.stackexchange.com](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/). Based on what you've told me, I would guess that `magnitude_spectrum` would be more appropriate for computing the magnitude component, for the phase you could presumably use [`phase_spectrum`](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.phase_spectrum) (remember that angular differences will need to be wrapped between -pi and pi).